# Exposing Fragment in React Native Android ViewManager

Tags: android, react-native, android-youtube-api

I am attempting to wrap the YouTube Android API as a UI Component for React Native. I have been successful in the Android configuration of things (getting onInitializationSuccess), however I am unable to figure out how get the YouTubePlayerView back to my React Native app.

According to the docs, they recommend using YouTubePlayerFragment if you can not extend YouTubeBaseActivity. Since React Native on Android does not use XML based layouts I attempted to create the views programmatically. However, when I return the wrapping View ( I tried as a FrameLayout, but not sure if that was the right choice) I created it does not render anything on the application.

I am looking to keep it extremely simple for now, here are the necessary bits of code:

**YouTubeManager.java**

```
public class YouTubeManager extends SimpleViewManager<FrameLayout>  implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
// ...
@Override
    protected FrameLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        this.reactContext = reactContext;

        FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(reactContext);
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        YouTubePlayerFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(view.getId(), fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        fragment.initialize("SECRET_KEY", this);

        return view;
    }
// ... 
}
```

**YouTube.js**

```
class YouTube extends Component {
    render () {
        return <YouTubeAndroid {...this.props}/>;
    }
};

var iface = {
    name : 'YouTube',
    propTypes : {
        ...View.propTypes
    },
};


var YouTubeAndroid = requireNativeComponent('YouTube', iface);

module.exports = YouTube;
```

**index.android.js**

```
var YouTube = require('./YouTube');

class YouTubePlayer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>hello</Text>
        <YouTube />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does setting explicit height and width on youtube component help ?

Comment: @agent_hunt yeah, I tried giving it a fixed height/width and backgroundColor. It just renders an empty view https://www.dropbox.com/s/3obfjs6agcux3z2/Screenshot%202016-03-26%2017.10.55.png?dl=0

Comment: Is the issue solved? Did you manage to render the Fragment?

Comment: @ischmierer yes using Deminoth's suggestion. This required extending the ReactActivity though, and it was a bit buggy. This method broke recently (fixed in 0.32-rc, though with `getCurrentActivity()` being available by `SimpleViewManager`).

Answer (score 7):

I don't have actual solution for the YouTube fragment, but I used some workaround for displaying an YouTube view in RN.

(Maybe you can try the hack in `3.` on your fragment first.)

1. Make your own `ReactActivity` that extends `YouTubeBaseActivity` and let `MainActivity` extends it.

   ```
   public abstract class ReactActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
     // copy & paste RN's ReactActivity.java source
   ```
2. Make `YoutubeManager` class for the `YouTubePlayerView`.

   It should takes an `Activity` instance from `createViewManagers` when you implements `ReactPackage`.

   ```
   public class YoutubeManager extends SimpleViewManager<YouTubePlayerView> implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener,  YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

     public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTYoutube";
     private static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "<YOUR_OWN_KEY>";

     private YouTubeBaseActivity mActivity = null;
     private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView = null;

     public YoutubeManager(Activity activity) {
       super();
       mActivity = (YouTubeBaseActivity) activity;
     }

     @Override
     public String getName() {
       return REACT_CLASS;
     }

     @Override
     public YouTubePlayerView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
       mContext = context;

       mYouTubePlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(mActivity);
       mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

       return mYouTubePlayerView;
     }
   ```

   and make a js module for it.

   ```
   module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTYoutube', iface);
   ```
3. Now You can display an YouTube view, but it seems like empty view. You need some hack for it.

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({
       width: this.props.style.width,
       height: this.props.style.height - 1
     })
     this.timer = setInterval(()=>{
       this.setState({
         width: this.props.style.width,
         height: this.props.style.height + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
       })
     }, 500)
   }

   render() {
     return (<YoutubeView style={[style, { width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }]} />)
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
     if(this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
   }
   ```

You can see how it works actually from my app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.dobbit.sharehows

Comment: Any idea why you need the delay (or the interval for that matter) for this to show up?